# How to stop foreach %dopar% without messing up the session

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I use the foreach dopar quite a bit in R to take advantage of the multi cores to speed things up in doing ad hoc analysis in interactive sessions.

However I have noticed sometimes if I break out from the parallelized for loops (typically when I realized I have got something wrong in the worker threads) by pressing control-c, the session will be messed up in the sense that when I use the foreach dopar again, things will be executed by one thread only (top wouldn't show multiple processes as usual plus the work will take ages compared to when parallelization works). It doesn't happening on every control-c, but frequent enough to be annoying (reloading everything the session has from a brand new session can be annoying)

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, or at least a way to fix the environment when it happens?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to register your clusters and then create a stop function that will automatically handle the cores if you exit the process.

```
myClusters <- makeCluster(4) #the number should reflect your system and project
registerDoParallel(myClusters)
```

and you can use something like

```
on.exit(stopCluster(myCluster))
```

If you set it up this way, then you should be ok when exit. You may need to run a

`gc()` in the console to get the cruft out....

Comment: Oh cool, i have been running with `killall -u me` for 2 years now